# PHP comes with an error of creating a temporary file but I am only using normal form input fields

Tags: php, post, iis

I have a very strange error in PHP and/or IIS which I cannot figure out at all. It seems I have a POST or an array variable nesting limit though I have tweaked everything I seem related. I get this error:

> **Notice**: Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in **Unknown** on line **0**
>
> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in **Unknown** on line **0**

I am having this setup:

- PHP 7.2.29
- Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS (8.5?)

What I am doing in my source page is really simple and I do **not** do any file handling at all so I should not be having any problems with temporary file uploads or alike. Nor should it actually at all try and create a temporary file!? All I have is a `form` with some `input` fields and then I do a `phpinfo()` on my destination page (for debugging effort).

I have this below source PHP page which has a static amount of data. I am outputting 100 rows and within each row I do have an array variable named `var`. This variable has a static value of `12345678`:

```
<?PHP
    echo "<form action='postpage.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' /><br><br>";
    for ($row = 0; $row < 100; $row++) {
        for ($column = 0; $column < 9; $column++) {
            echo "<input type='text' name='var[]' value='12345678' /> ";
        }
    echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "</form>";
?>
```

My `postpage.php` only has this content:

```
<?PHP
    phpinfo();
?>
```

But when I click **Submit** on my form then I get the error as shown above and `phpinfo()` does **not** show any POST or REQUEST variables at all!?

The interesting part is that when I change the static value from `12345678` to `1234567` then everything works! Also if I tweak the variable name and amount of rows or columns then I can tweak it but I always run in to problems with what I dare saying is a fairly small amount of data.

I would believe that there would be PHP or IIS setting but I have tried everything I know and these are the settings I have now:

PHP:

- max_input_nesting_level = 10000
- max_input_vars = 100000
- memory_limit = 512M
- post_max_size = 512M

IIS (IIS Manager > MyServer > Request Filtering > Query Strings > Edit Feature Settings):

- Maximum URL length = 65536
- Maximum query string = 32768

Does anyone have any idea for what I can look in to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more troubleshooting I found the problem - **it was a faulty directory for** `upload_tmp_dir` **in** `php.ini`

Though I did not change this directory setting the last few years and I expected it to work then apparently it did not. Not many weeks ago I did update PHP from 7.2.x to a newer version of 7.2.x but did not encounter this problem until now.

When I updated the directory to the correct upload directory then it suddenly came with another error:

> **Warning**: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in **Unknown** on line **0**

This error I can relate to and after changing that to a higher value then everything works :-)

I can see that in PHP 7.1 [tempnam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) now throws a `Notice` so my current guess is that maybe a cookie or alike is using this method and then throws a notice which overrule the other error.

If you have a better answer then please propose as I then will accept that as the answer as I am not trying to ask questions and just accept my own answers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answer by Beauvais I checked my php.ini which was set, enabled and read

upload_tmp_dir = G:\www\temp

I was unaware that the directory 'temp' had not been created in G:\www

After creating the directory and running the program the warning did not appear.

Hope this is of use to others.